# Laravel search function query builder

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to write a function which handles a search query for my website

I have a field called 'unique' which has a true or false value for this search. Because this page will be listing non unique results i need it as e.g `'unique' , '!=', true`

i have 2 other fields `name, description` so when you search it returns the expected results

I have written the below code but if i click search on the page it will list all the results regardless if the unique field is true or false and if i search for a name or description that returns results ignoring the unique.

```
    $films = Film::when($request->input('unique'), function ($query) {
        $query->where('unique', '!=', true);
    })
        ->where('name', 'like', "%$search%")
        ->orWhere('description', 'like', "%$search%")
        ->get();
```

Im not very knowlegable when it comes to eloquent queries so i maybe missing something here.

Summarise functionality i need: If i search without entering in the search box field only return records that have unique as TRUE and if i search for a name or description in the text field only return records that match the input and with the unique being TRUE.

Any feedback would be great, thanks!

Comment: In SQL ```!=``` is ```<>```. See https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-not-equal-operator/

Comment: To state the obvious, you can use ```where('unique', false)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got your question, but might this be a solution to your problem:

```
$filmQuery = Film::where('unique', false);
if($search !== "") {
   $filmQuery = $filmQuery->where(function ($query) {
       $query->where('name', 'like', "%$search%")
       ->orWhere('description', 'like', "%$search%");
   });
}
$films = $filmQuery->get();
```

This should get you all the Films, where either `'name'` or `'description'` match your `$search` and which also have `'unique' === false`.

And if `$search === ""` (empty) you should get all the films where `'unique' === false`.

Comment: I have records which have a true or false value for a field called unique, I am only wanting to display records with a unique as false within all search results. the name and description are just fields I can input to search for and if they match a record return it.

Comment: I edited my answer to false, but I'm still a bit lost, Sorry. Above code should return all Film entries, where unique === false. And if $search has a value it should additionally only get you the entries where the search criteria ist met. Can you test the code? Does it do what you want?

Comment: I would love to help, but some feedback would be vital. Do you have an input checkbox in your html form for the unique value?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your question, but might this be a solution to your problem:

```
$id = $request->id;
$search = $request->search;

$data = DB::table('invoice');
$data = $data->select('*');
if($search !== "") {
  $data = $data->where('id', '=', $id);
}
$data = $data->get();
```